# AmCharts - Cannot read property 'none' of undefined

Tags: jquery, amcharts

Im trying to have a chart of AMCHART,

I render it, and it seems having a problem, the error I get is :

```
Cannot read property 'none' of undefined
```

I think its something to do with the theme, and the file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/none.js"></script>
```

(which i pleaced it in the last of the all js files i have..)

any thoughts what may cause the problem?

Comment: Well, we cannot help without the js code that throws the error. It should tell you what file and what line the error occurs. That is the code you need to look at. There will be an object you try to access a property from and that property will be named by some expression.

Comment: place it at first of all js files, some of your code is looking for `AmCharts.themes.none={};` but cant find it as its not defined yet